# xsl choose when xpath not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following code. It does not appear to trigger. Basically I want to disable the radio button 'overdraft' when 'personal' is checked  . If there are any easier ways or if you can see what I am doing wrong. I have tried both options below.

```
<td class="Label" colspan="1" width="50%">
    <input class="Label" type="radio" name="selectedFacilityType" value="1" onClick="document.lending.selectedFacilityTypeValue.value=this.value">
        <xsl:if test="facilitytype/options[@id='1']='checked'">
            <xsl:attribute name="checked"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- start -->
        <xsl:if test="lettertype/type[@id='personal']='checked'">
            <xsl:attribute disabled="disabled"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- end -->
    </input>Overdraft
 </td>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="lettertype/type[@id='personal']='checked'">
        <td class="Label" colspan="1" width="50%">
            <input class="Label" type="radio" name="selectedFacilityType" value="1" onClick="document.lending.selectedFacilityTypeValue.value=this.value" disabled="disabled"></input>Overdraft
        </td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise> 
        <td class="Label" colspan="1" width="50%">
            <input class="Label" type="radio" name="selectedFacilityType" value="1" onClick="document.lending.selectedFacilityTypeValue.value=this.value">
            <xsl:if test="facilitytype/options[@id='1']='checked'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </input>Overdraft
        </td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Sample xml:

```
<lending>
<currentbaserate/>
<lettertype>
    <type id="personal">checked</type>
    <type id="business"/>
    <type id="limited"/>
</lettertype>
<saved/>
<applicantdetails>
    <name>
        <title/>
        <firstname/>
        <surname/>
    </name>
    <address>
        <addressline1/>
        <addressline2/>
        <addressline3/>
        <addressline4/>
        <addressline5/>
    </address>
    <ourref/>
    <date/>
    <salutation/>
    <facilitysought/>
    <signame/>
    <sigposition/>
    <signameadd/>
    <sigpositionadd/>
</applicantdetails>
<facilitytype>
    <options id="1">checked</options>
    <options id="2"/>
    <options id="3"/>
    <options id="4"/>
    <options id="5"/>
    <options id="6"/>
    <options id="7"/>
    <options id="8"/>
</facilitytype>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using javascript to disable the radio button

Answer (score 0):

for each xpath you should use '//' before:

like instead of

```
<xsl:if test="facilitytype/options[@id='1']='checked'">
```

use

```
<xsl:if test="//facilitytype/options[@id='1']='checked'">
```

add this in all instance in this script.

it can result your desired output

Comment: the xsl choose when works but it just disables the overdraft button for all lettertypes e.g. personal, business, limited. I want it just to disable for when personal is checked

Comment: you can use this //lettertype[type/@id='personal'][type='checked']

Comment: srry that didnt work. I have <input id="ltype" type="hidden" value="personal"/> . I basically want to disable a radio button with maybe <xsl:if test="//input[@id='ltype'][@type='hidden'][@value='personal']">
                  <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:if>